# Using JQuery to get the value of the unchecked checkboxes in a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to store the `values` from a set of unchecked `html` checkboxes. I understand that `JQuery` does not have an :unchecked selector so I must invert the :checked selector. I've done this and I am getting the values of the unchecked boxes as well as a number of other values such as `null` and `0`. I don't know where these are coming from.

Here is my `HTML`:

```
   <div id="tag_results">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="29" name="tag" checked=""></input>
                Agriculture
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="30" name="tag" checked=""></input>
                Angling
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="37" name="tag"></input>
                Animals
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="54" name="tag" checked=""></input>
                Arts
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my `JQuery`:

```
    $('#saveBtn').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                //Get hidden field values and store in an Array

                $tagArray = [];
                $removeTags = [];

                //Get the Checked Tags and store in an Array(will be added)
                $('#tag_results :checked').each(function(){
                    $tagArray.push(this.value);
                });

                //Get the Unchecked Tags and Store in an Array(will be removed)
                $('#tag_results :not(:checked)').each(function(){
                    $removeTags.push(this.value);
                });

                console.log($removeTags);

                //Make Ajax request to the add_tags script and pass Array as parameter. When response recieved show dialog. 
                //Pass the name, id and type of company with the array of tags to the save_tags.php script. 
                $('#active_tags').load('pages/ajax/save_tags.php', {'removeTags': JSON.stringify($removeTags),'tags': JSON.stringify($tagArray) ,'name': $('#comp_name').val(), 'id': $('#comp_id').val(), 'type': $('#type').val() }, function(response, status, xhr){
                });
   });
```

this is the result of `console.log`:

```
Array [ undefined, 0, 0, 0, "37", 0, "54" ]
```

This is the code I use to generate the `html` for the checkboxes:

```
$output = "<ul>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){//If results returned (tags found matching letter) so construct list
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){//while there are rows in the results array add a list item 
            if(in_array($row['name'], $applied_tags)){
                $output .= "<li>" .'<input checked type="checkbox" name="tag" value="'.$row['id'].'">' .$row['name'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
            }else{
                $output .= "<li>" .'<input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="'.$row['id'].'">' .$row['name'] .'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }else{//Else there was no matching tags so display an error message to the user. 
        $output .= "<li>No Tags found beginning with the letter " . $letter . "</li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
```

Does anyone have any clue what could be causing this? Surely based on the above code the array should contain the values 37 and 54...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Why was my original code not working though??

Comment: Its happens because of not mentioning type of element.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, will accept answer in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you `did not mention check box or name of checkbox` , so it w`ill selected all children of  tag_results` and check the all element

```
$('#tag_results [type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function () {
    $removeTags.push(this.value);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dbr8dxmu/1/)**

NOTE: `$('#tag_results :not(:checked)')` will select all children element except checked